# How to convert and display the value from the database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I want do display outlet name as "Food" if the value in the database is "FC" and display "Express" if the value in the database is "EX" in my for each drop down.

Here's my controller

```
$outlet_name = StoreFC::select('loc_type')
      ->groupBy('loc_type')
      ->orderBy('loc_type', 'ASC')
      ->get();

$district_name = StoreFC::select('location')
    ->groupBy('location')
      ->orderBy('location', 'ASC')
      ->get();
 return view('test.store-fc', compact('outlet_name','district_name'));
```

Here's my view

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select name="filter_district" id="filter_district" class="form-control" required>
     <option value="">Select Location</option>
       @foreach ($district_name as $district)
          <option value="{{ $district->location }}">{{ $district->location }}</option>
       @endforeach
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select name="filter_outlet" id="filter_outlet" class="form-control" required>
     <option value="">Select Outlet</option>
        @foreach($outlet_name as $outlet)
           <option value="{{ $outlet->loc_type }}">{{ $outlet->loc_type }}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Here's my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class StoreFC extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'store_foodcity';
    }
```

This is how it show now in the drop down

[image: This is how it show now in the drop down]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom getters in model StoreFC.

[https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor][1]

The best thing U can do is to create a new column with the full name "Food" for "FX", otherwize.... you have to modify that mutator every time U change something in database.